# Find which element of the stream does not match the given predicate in allmatch

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to find out which element is failing the predicate in case of `allmatch`.

```
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
boolean isEven = numbers.stream().allMatch(n-> n % 2 == 0);
```

Here `isEven` is `false`, as element `1` fails the predicate.

I can use `forEach` over the stream to find which element fails like:

```
numbers.stream().forEach(n -> {
            if (n % 2 != 0)
                System.out.println(n + "is Odd");
        });
```

Is there a way to figure out which elements fails the predicate in the `allmatch` when it returns `false`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please remember that `allMatch` is a short-circuiting operation, meaning that the stream API may return false without finding all the elements that fail the test.

So if you want to find **all** the failing elements, you might have to do more work than a simple `allMatch` (as shown by other answers).  However, if you only care to find one element that fails the test, use `findAny` as follows:

```
Optional<Integer> odd = numbers.stream()
    .filter(n -> n % 2 != 0)
    .findAny();

boolean isEven = !odd.isPresent();

odd.ifPresent(x -> System.out.println(x + " is odd"));
```

Answer (score 5):

For this example:

```
Map<Boolean, List<Integer>> map = numbers.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(x -> x % 2 == 0));

    System.out.println(map); // {false=[1, 3, 5], true=[2, 4]}
```

You could simply log it for example also:

```
boolean isEven = numbers.stream().allMatch(n -> {
        boolean test = n % 2 == 0;
        if (!test) {
            System.out.println("Failed = " + n);
        }
        return test;
    });
```

But this might introduce interesting results if you run it in `parallel`. The output would be un-predictable. That is `isEven` is still going to return the correct result, but what you see via `Syso` is completely un-predicatable. Could be :

```
 Failed = 3
 Failed = 1
 Failed = 5
```

And on another run could be:

```
 Failed = 3
```

Comment: Thank you @Eugene, I should have been more specific. I agree this solves the given example, but I am actually trying to write a test case and would like to know the first / any element for which the predicate fails. I was using `forEach Assert` thus able to determine where the element fails the predicate but I am not able to do a similar thing with `assert allmatch`. Is there a way I could find the element which fails when doing something like `assert allmatch`?

Comment: @sanchitkum you could inverse your logic. If *at least* one is not even.. `boolean allEven = !numbers.stream().filter(n -> !(n % 2 == 0)).findAny().isPresent();`

Comment: @sanchitkum this `numbers.stream().filter(n -> !(n % 2 == 0)).findAny()` returns an `Optional` that might contain the value that fails (if it is non-empty). But notice that `findAny` and `findFirst` are different things and might return different values if the stream is parallel, you need to know which one you actually want.

Comment: @sanchitkum no worries

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
List<Integer> notMatchElements = numbers.stream()
               .filter(n -> n % 2 == 0)
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If notMatchElements length equals 0 -> all match

Else -> you got not match elements

Answer (score 0):

You need to split this two action (filtering out and verifying all match into two actions)

```
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
List<Integer> notMatched = numbers
                            .stream()
                            .filter(n-> n % 2 != 0)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
boolean isEven = notMatched.isEmpty();
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose to use this approach :

```
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

List<Integer> badNumbers = numbers.stream().filter(n -> n % 2 != 0).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In this case `badNumbers` will be empty if all elements satisfy `n%2 = 0` otherwise it will contains values that doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Something need to clarify: a `boolean` is not a `Predicate`. `boolean` is a **noun**, but `Predicate` is a **predicate**. so your `Predicate` is more like this:

```
IntPredicate isEven = n -> n % 2 == 0;

boolean numbersAreEven = numbers.stream().allMatch(isEven);
```

**IF** you need to inverse a `Predicate` you can using [Predicate#negate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html#negate--), for example:

```
IntPredicate isOdd = isEven.negate();

boolean numbersAreOdd = numbers.stream().allMatch(isOdd);
```

**IF** you want to list all odd numbers, you should use [Stream#filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-), for example:

```
numbers.stream().filter(isOdd).forEach(System.out::println);
```

**IF** you want to find the first odd number, you can use [Stream#findFirst](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--), for example:

```
Number odd = numbers.stream().filter(isOdd).findFirst().orElse(null);
```

**IF** you want to find the first odd number regardless of the elements order, you can use [Stream#findAny](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findAny--), for example:

```
Number odd = numbers.stream().filter(isOdd).findAny().orElse(null);
```

*Note*: both [Stream#findAny](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findAny--) and [Stream#findFirst](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--) are [short-circuiting terminal operation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps), which means it will exit once any [intermediate operation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps) is satisfied.